# How to locate terraforming candidates without clicking every single planet in every single system

Tags: stellaris

So I've unlocked terraforming. Yay!  I know I've discovered something like three candidates. Yay!

Time to put two and to together to make terrafourm!

"Planets and Sectors" seems to only list sectors.  I know I can see candidate status on the planet view, but I've got nearly two dozen systems within my borders at this point.  That's a LOT of individual planets to click. Is there some other way to quickly navigate to and determine the status of terraforming candidates?

This question is for PC.

Comment: Are you on the console or PC version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Expansion Planner (F5 on PC) & Sort by Habitability. 0% Habitability Planets are the Terraforming Candidates.
Of course you can terraform planets of higher habitability too.

Comment: You will also notice that all such candidate planets have a special modifier listed in the expansion planner - "Terraforming candidate"

Comment: I can't seem to get at the planets from there, which feels like poor UI design, but that absolutely gets me the list. Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII Unless you've got some unfortunate mod changing up the Expansion Planner's UI, the cameras in the left-most column should take you directly to the planet in the system view.  I also believe that double clicking on the planet icon in the 2nd column should bring up the planet's UI.

Comment: Unmodded, no such functionality. Camera icon, weirdly, brings me to the system... but does not activate system view. Haven't tried it while already in system view, mind you.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII Double clicking on the camera icon should do the trick. This also works for other times where you use the camera icon (ships, events, ...)

Comment: @xyldke Never thought to double-click that! I'll try it tonight!